# Источник интересной информации о PHP

Tags: php

Хотелось бы читать RSS какие-нибудь о PHP. Качественный материал, хороших блоггеров, незнаю что еще, главное чтобы влиться в мир PHP на всю катушку.

Кто что читает ?

Спасибо.

Comment: Не удержался. Вначале тотуриалы, потом мануалы, а потом уже исходный код php-интерпретатора :)))

Comment: А потом изучение другого языка(после изучения исходников интерпритатора :D)

Comment: Курить маны это хорошо, но хочется почитать про чужой опыт. =)

Comment: > А потом изучение другого языка

Зачем потом? Это все можно делать параллельно. На опыте разработки это скажется исключительно положительно :)

Comment: Называется помогли человеку :DDD

Answer (score 2):

Читайте доки - они RULEZ :-)

Ну а если серьезно, то собственно PHP вторично, изучайте принципы программирования. А уже зная принципы можно писать хоть на PHP хоть на любом другом процедурном или ОО-языке. Собственно для того что-бы зная **что и как** вы хотите написать вам понадобится только документация доступная на php.net

Касаемо рунета по PHP есть несколько толковых форумов ([phpforum.ru](http://phpforum.ru/), [phpclub.ru](http://phpclub.ru/), [раздел форума PHP на sql.ru](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualtopics.aspx?bid=18)) а вот чего-нибудь из блогоподобного можно с натяжкой назвать [раздел PHP на habrahabr.ru](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/)